# Template Not Detecting Plugin Class?

Tags: templates, php, plugin

Working on a plugin integrating with the Active Campaign API.

What I have is a folder inside third_party containing pi.ActiveCampaign.php with a lib folder containing the API. The class describing the plugin is "Active_Campaign" and the function I want to use with it is "insert_contacts." The plugin appears in the add-ons section just fine, with all my documentation, but when I try to use it in a template:

[image]

It appears to not be detecting it. I've tried just using "exp:insert_contacts" as well, same result.

Here's the PHP file, as it is now, if needed (bitbucket repo): https: https://goo.gl/Shm4JN

And for reference, here's the doc I'm following: https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/plugins.html

jic.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

FOUND IT!

I feel stupid. It was a case sensitivity issue with the file name. It was pi.ActiveCampaign.php but needed to be pi.active_campaign.php.

Comment: could you please mark you answer is correct one? thanks!